# Structure and logic issues on my Blackjack game Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pygame, blackjack

I am writing a Blackjack game for a school assignment and I try to understand certain parts of the structure/logic.

Currently, I am having issues getting my randomly generated cards to sum for the player/dealer hand. Furthermore, I am having issues with the structure and calling my functions in `main()`.

```
import random
Dealer_Chips = 500
Player_Chips = 500
Pot = 0

deck = {'Two': 2, 'Three' : 3, 'Four' : 4, 'Five' : 5, 'Six' : 6, 'Seven' : 7, 'Eight' : 8, 'Nine' : 9, 'Jack' : 10, 'Queen' :10, 'King' : 10, 'Ace' : 11}

Player_Hand = [random.choice(list(deck)), random.choice(list(deck))] #Creates Player hand
Dealer_Hand = [random.choice(list(deck)), random.choice(list(deck))] #Creats Dealer Hand
Player_Score = 0
Dealer_Score = 0

    enter code here

def Ace():
    if Player_Hand == 'Ace':
        input("You drew an Ace, Please choose whether the Ace is a 1 or 11")



def Hit():
    Player_Hand + random.choice(list(deck))
    print("You chose to Hit, Your hand is", Player_Hand)


def Stay():
    print ("stay")


def Bet():
    input("Please place a bet. Bets can be either 5, 10, 25, 50")
if input == 5:
        Pot + 5
        if input == 10:
            Pot + 10
            if input == 25:
                Pot + 25
                if input == 50:
                    Pot + 50

def Winner():
    print("Congratulations, you win!")
    Player_Chips + Pot

def Main():
    print("Welcome to Blackjack!")
    print("Your Hand is", Player_Hand, "Your Chip Count is", Player_Chips)
    input == Bet()
    input("Would you like to hit or stay? Enter H to hit, or S to stay")
    if input == "H":
        Hit()
    if input == "S":
        Stay()





Main()
```

Comment: Can you please provide what you are trying to do and what is going wrong? Also some output of your code would be helpful in debugging

Comment: Sorry for not adding the output. Here is what is happening.  # Welcome to Blackjack!
Your Hand is ['Seven', 'Ace'] Your Chip Count is 500
Please place a bet. Bets can be either 5, 10, 25, 50
Would you like to hit or stay? Enter H to hit, or S to stay. I input H, and the game finishes.

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 1):

Here we go :)

> ```py
> input("Would you like to hit or stay? Enter H to hit, or S to stay")
> ```

**`input` is a builtin function.** You are confusing it with a variable. You need to create a variable with a different name (I will use `Input_Variable` for the rest of this answer), and you need to store the result of `input()` in said variable. Like this:

```py
InputVariable = input("Would you like to hit or stay? Enter H to hit, or S to stay")
```

> ```py
> input == Bet()
> ```

**`Input_Variable == x` and `Input_Variable = x` are not the same thing.** `Input_Variable == x` *checks* if `Input_Variable` is equal to x, and `Input_Variable = x` *makes* `Input_Variable` equal to x.

> ```py
> def Bet():
>     InputVariable = input("Please place a bet. Bets can be either 5, 10, 25, 50")
> if InputVariable == 5:
> ```

**In Python, you need to indent lines to make them a part of a statement.** Your indentation needs to be consistent too:

```py
def Bet():
    input("Please place a bet. Bets can be either 5, 10, 25, 50")
    if input == 5: # this needs to be indented by four spaces or one tab
        # more code goes here, indented by eight spaces or two tabs
```

> ```py
> if input == 5:
>     Pot + 5
>     if input == 10:
>         Pot + 10
>         if input == 25:
>             Pot + 25
>             if input == 50:
>                 Pot + 50
> ```

**`Pot + 5` does not add 5 to Pot, then store the result in Pot:** if you want to add 5 to Pot and store the result in Pot, you need to do something like `Pot = Pot + 5`.

Also, there is no point in doing things this way. Just do

```py
Pot = Pot + InputValue
```

> ```py
> Player_Hand = [random.choice(list(deck)), random.choice(list(deck))]
> ```

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do here, but it doesn't seem right. Please clarify.

I may have missed a few things, but hopefully this will have helped you. Good luck in your school assignment!

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Setting the player's Bet input to a variable and then adding that variable to the pot, makes a lot more sense. As for this part  # Player_Hand = [random.choice(list(deck)), random.choice(list(deck))] #, I was attempting to randomly draw from the deck and place two random cards into the player and dealers hands. Once I had done this, I would add both cards together giving me the functionality to compare and determine who one the round of BlackJack. Lastly, thankyou for explaining the difference between = and ==, This clarifies an error I was receiving.

Answer (score 1):

There's still a good amount of work to do on this code so I'll make notes on a few things that stand out to me.

```
def Bet():
    input("Please place a bet. Bets can be either 5, 10, 25, 50")
if input == 5:
        Pot + 5
        if input == 10:
            Pot + 10
            if input == 25:
                Pot + 25
                if input == 50:
                    Pot + 50
```

1. Not sure if this is just a copy+paste error, but the indentation on this is all off -- your chain of `if`s starts outside of your function definition, so they're not going to happen as part of the function.
2. Your `if` statements are nested inside of each other, which means that the inner ones will never happen (because it's not possible for `input` to be simultaneously, say, 5 and 10).
3. None of them will ever happen anyway because you `input` a string and are comparing against ints.
4. You're not looking at the value the `input` function returned, you're comparing against the `input` function itself.

A fixed version of this function might look like:

```
def Bet():
    # Get the bet from the user by inputting a string and converting it to an int.
    bet = int(input("Please place a bet. Bets can be either 5, 10, 25, 50: "))
    # Make sure that the bet is within the set of allowed values.
    assert(bet in [5, 10, 25, 50])
    # Add it to the Pot global variable.
    Pot += bet
```

Now, looking at the `Main()` function:

```
def Main():
    print("Welcome to Blackjack!")
    print("Your Hand is", Player_Hand, "Your Chip Count is", Player_Chips)
    input == Bet()  # see notes 1, 2, and 3
    input("Would you like to hit or stay? Enter H to hit, or S to stay") # 4
    if input == "H":
        Hit()  # 5
    if input == "S":
        Stay()
```

1. `Bet()` does not return any value, so there's no reason to assign something to its return.
2. Assigning something to the `input` function is going to make that function unusable.
3. The equality operator `==` doesn't work for assigning something.
4. Again, you need to assign a value to `input`'s return, e.g. `action = input("...")`
5. Once you've either `Hit()` or `Stay()`ed, you need to do more to update the state of the game.  If you `Hit()` you want to go back and prompt the user again, and if you `Stay()` then you want to add up the scores.

I think you need more help with this than a single stackoverflow answer can give, so I'd recommend talking to your teacher and asking them for guidance on how they expect you to complete the assignment -- for example, have they explained loops to you yet?

Good luck!  :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do understand that the indentation in the betting function is very wonky and poorly written. For some reason, I thought that with IF decisions they had to be indented. I am going to rewrite this portion. I agree that I do need more help and practice, programming has never been my strongest skill. I am going to revisit and add to the Hit() and Stay() portion to keep the game going. This was actually a major issue because my deck wasn't comparing the player/dealer hand values and made it difficult to write the next portion of the game. All this advice is very helpful.

Comment: Also thank you for showing me "Assert", I have never seen this before and it looks like such a better way to validate input within the allowed betting range.

Comment: `if` statements do need to be indented, but where exactly you put the indentation matters; you can't just hit Tab randomly and expect your program to do what you want.  :)  Anything you indent under an `if` only happens `if` the predicate is true -- so if you nest an `if` inside of an `if`, then the thing inside **that** only happens if **both** predicates are true (and if the two predicates are `n == 5` and `n == 10` they can't *both* be true at the same time, right?).